# Google Spreadsheet: Anyone can edit but not able to save the changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to publish a Google Spreadsheet on a webpage in playground mode which would enable the visitors to edit the content, change the formulas etc. but all those changes must remain local and not be saved in the original Google Spreadsheet.

Is it possible to publish and embed such a Google Spreadsheet like disabling the 'Save' functionality for end-users i.e. unable to auto-save on changes and can't save manually too?

Any solution will do that even if it involves Google Apps Script! Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy method to maintain the integrity of a master spreadsheet while allowing people to edit is to just force a copy when they click the link.

Your spreadsheet needs, at minimum, view rights in the sharing settings. Then, grab the URL:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SOME_BIG_LONG_KEY/view`

Change "view" at the end to "copy":

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SOME_BIG_LONG_KEY/copy`

The user will be asked to sign in and save a copy to their Drive. Your master remain untouched, everyone has a working copy of the sheet, and you don't need a big script to manage changes.

That being said, if you make changes to the master, they aren't reflected in the copy because it's a new document.

Comment: @cooper not sure if it's officially documented...I learned about it somewhere a couple years back and use it regularly.

Comment: Do you share with another user and then change the view on that link to /copy?

Comment: @cooper Yes. Minimum permission is 'view' because Drive needs to be able to open it before making the copy. Essentially the same as using `DriveApp.openFileById().copy()` through GAS. You need permission to open the file - not edit - for the GAS methods to work.

Comment: Yeah, you could make and share a copy using GAS, can't do that with  the URL trick. I started playing with storing the original range in a property to write back out using an `onOpen` trigger, but had trouble getting the values from the stored range. Need to play more next week.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to put some of the functionality of a spreadsheet in a web app.  This example is a trivial beginning to what you would want.  As far as disabling saving that might be achieved by creating a copy of the spreadsheet you want and and the deleting it via DriveApp when you leave the web app (not sure how to do that).  It might be possible but my guess is that it's a lot of work and I'm not sure it will perform as well as just using the standard spreadsheet. Brian Bennet's solution is probably a better idea but then that user keeps a copy of the spreadsheet that you have no control over.  So that may not be what you want either.

Code.gs:

```
var SSID='SpreadsheetID';
var sheetName='Sheet Name';
function htmlSpreadsheet(mode)
{
  var mode=(typeof(mode)!='undefined')?mode:'dialog';
  var br='<br />';
  var s='';
  var hdrRows=1;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  s+='<table>';
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    s+='<tr>';
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[i].length;j++)
    {
      if(i<hdrRows)
      {
        s+='<th id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="10" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      } 
      else
      {
        s+='<td id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="10" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      }
    }
    s+='</tr>';
  }
  s+='</table>';
  //s+='<div id="success"></div>';
  s+='</body></html>';
  switch (mode)
  {
    case 'dialog':
      var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlss').setWidth(1000).setHeight(450);
      userInterface.append(s);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Spreadsheet Data for ' + ss.getName() + ' Sheet: ' + sht.getName());
      break;
    case 'web':
      var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlss').setWidth(1000).setHeight(450);
      return userInterface.append(s).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
   }
}

function updateSpreadsheet(i,j,value)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  rngA[i][j]=value;
  rng.setValues(rngA);
  var data = {'message':'Cell[' + Number(i + 1) + '][' + Number(j + 1) + '] Has been updated', 'ridx': i, 'cidx': j};
  return data;
}

function doGet()
{
  var output=htmlSpreadsheet('web');
  return output;
}
```

htmlss.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {

    });
    function updateSS(i,j)
    {
      var str='#txt' + String(i) + String(j);
      var value=$(str).val();
      $(str).css('background-color','#ffff00');
      google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(successHandler)
         .updateSpreadsheet(i,j,value)
    }
    function successHandler(data)
    {
      $('#success').text(data.message);
      $('#txt' + data.ridx + data.cidx).css('background-color','#ffffff');
    }
    console.log('My Code');
    </script>
    <style>
      th{text-align:left}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="success"></div>
```