# Google Script: Editors can't save data from sidebar in the sheet

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-sheets, publish, sidebar

The HTML sidebar get user input and save it in sheet:

1. with sheet's owner, it works fine (the data from sidebar are
   correctly saved in the sheet)
2. **with others sheet editors the data from sidebar is NOT been saved in the sheet**.

Owner and users at same domain
Apps Script Dashboard shows NO error

I would be very grateful for any help on how I can fix this issue.

SIDEBAR SOURCE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Style should be in the head -->
<style>
    .info {
        margin: 5px;
        width: 95%;
        padding: 2px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .msg {
        margin: 5px;
        width: 95%;
        padding: 2px;
        font-size: 13px;    
    }

    .container,
    .buttons {
        margin: 5px;
        width: 95%;
        padding: 2px;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
</style>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="msg"> 
      <p align="justify">Marque todos os motivos que levaram ao indeferimento do requerimento</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="info">
      <p id="stdname"></p>
      <p id="stamp"></p>
      <p id="applied"></p>
      <p id="eRange"></p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
      <?!=rngValid?>
    </div>
    
    <div class="buttons">
      <p>
        <button class="action" id="action" onclick="saveReasons();">Salvar motivos</button>
      </p>
      <br>             
    </div>
    <!-- These should be in the head. They should be there prior to page loading-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI/6e6d051d47b598ebab05857545f242caf2b4b48c/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
      var stamp    = <?= stamp ?>;
      var to       = <?= to ?>;
      var subject  = <?= subject ?>;
      var stdName  = <?= stdName ?>;
      var apply    = <?= apply ?>;      
      var eRange   = <?= eRange ?>;
      
      document.getElementById("stdname").innerHTML = stdName;
      document.getElementById("stamp").innerHTML   = stamp;
      document.getElementById("applied").innerHTML = apply;
      document.getElementById("eRange").innerHTML  = eRange;

      
      function saveReasons() {
        var selected = [];
        //get all checkboxes
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("ui.checkbox");
        console.log("checkboxes length: "+ checkboxes.length);
        console.log("checkboxes: "+ checkboxes);
            $("input:checkbox[name=sel]:checked").each(function() {
              selected.push($(this).val());
              $(this).prop( "checked", false ); 
            })

        console.log("selected: "+ selected);
        console.log("eRange: "+ eRange);
        
        google.script.run
          .withFailureHandler(() => {console.log("Error running script")})
          .process(selected,stdName, apply, eRange);
      }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

DEV TOOLS CONSOLE:

```
Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY           386795301-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:67
Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE           userCodeAppPanel:36
Error running script
```

Comment: So it looks like you have a failure in gs function process.

Comment: Sounds like an authentication issue.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511131/7215091

Comment: Can you provide your code,gs part? Does the function run on trigger? Do you slect "show sidebar" from the custom menu?

Comment: Hi Cooper, tks for your reply. I think so; I was accessing as anonymous.

Hi ziganotschka, tks for your reply. No, there's no trigger on process(). Sidebar runs from an onEdit trigger.

What I did:
-  I accessed like owner by a NON anonymnous ;
- Apps Script Dashboard then shows some erros (but incredible that these erros did not affected that owner could save data).
- I corrected the erros and now everthing is working fine.

Sorry for any inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

On your client-side code there is the following

```
google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(() => {console.log("Error running script")})
      .process(selected,stdName, apply, eRange);
```

The problem with the above code is that it give very low help to debug the main problem.

To get a meaningful error message replace

```
.withFailureHandler(() => {console.log("Error running script")})
```

to

```
.withFailureHandler((error) => {console.log('%s, %s',error.message, error.stack)})
```

Comment: Rubén, tks for your reply. I'm sure this will hepl me very much on next projects.