# Editable table in html and changes made will also save on the spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've created a website using google app script. In my website, I have a table but the values came from my spreadsheet.

Now, I have an editable table unfortunately, once I change the values in the row and the auto refresh triggered it will come back to normal and get the original values from the spreadsheet. Is there a way that once I've made some changes it will also change in the spreadsheet so when autorefresh triggered it will just be the same? Is it even possible?

```js
<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getOnline();
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable1).getStatus();
  
  setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementById("tablebody").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("tablebody1").innerHTML = "";
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getOnline();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable1).getStatus();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getOnline).generateTable();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getStatus).generateTable1();
  }, 20000); // run the function every 5 seconds
  

});

function generateTable(dataArray){

  var tbody = document.getElementById("tablebody");
  var tbody1 = document.getElementById("tablebody").innerHTML;
  
  dataArray.forEach(function(r){
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var col1 = document.createElement("td");
  col1.textContent = r[0];
  var col2 = document.createElement("td");
  col2.textContent = r[1];
  var col3 = document.createElement("td");
  col3.textContent = r[2];

  row.appendChild(col1);
  row.appendChild(col2);
  row.appendChild(col3);

  tbody.appendChild(row);

$(function(){
  $("td").click(function(event){
    if($(this).children("input").length > 0)
          return false;

    var tdObj = $(this);
    var preText = tdObj.html();
    var inputObj = $("<input type='text' />");
    tdObj.html("");

    inputObj.width(tdObj.width())
            .height(tdObj.height())
            .css({border:"0px",fontSize:"17px"})
            .val(preText)
            .appendTo(tdObj)
            .trigger("focus")
            .trigger("select");

    inputObj.keyup(function(event){
      if(13 == event.which) { // press ENTER-key
        var text = $(this).val();
        tdObj.html(text);
      }
      else if(27 == event.which) {  // press ESC-key
        tdObj.html(preText);
      }
    });

    inputObj.click(function(){
      return false;
    });
  });
});
});
 
}
</script>
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Timestamp & Current TimeZone</th>        
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>EID</th>
      </tr>
     <tbody id="tablebody">         
    </table>
```

Here's my code on .gs

```
function getOnline(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("UserLogins");
var data = ws.getRange(3, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();
Logger.log(data);
return data;
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Google Spreadsheet: Anyone can edit but not able to save the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501855/google-spreadsheet-anyone-can-edit-but-not-able-to-save-the-changes) ?

Comment: It was helpful but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question. Anyways thank you for sharing that content, i'll used it to my future updates.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure of your use case, but it’s possible to embed an editable spreadsheet ([see how here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)).

If you really want to do this with HTML + JavaScript for yourself, my approach would be:

1. Keep a version of what you know is in the backend. And another of the local changes, in different data structures.
2. Use functional paradigms to generate the table. Specially reactive frameworks (React, Vue.js, etc) will simplify your job a lot.
3. When “applying” changes, do not manually modify the backend data representation.
4. It should be kept as the data that the server sends you. Simply send the request and it will be updated automatically.
   When the server sends a change that you had locally, remove it from the local changes. This consolidates the changes.

Also, you need to decide what happens when a cell gets updated while you are editing it.

Here is an example with vanilla JS on a single text input which can give you an idea (a lot of this could be handled by a reactive framework):

```js
const elements = {
  input: null,
  stateView: null
}

const backend = {
  input: 'value'
}
const local = {

}

function update() {
  // Update backend with the backend information. Usually means a fetch
  /* backend = ... */

  if (local.input === backend.input) {
    delete local.input
  }
  render()
}
function save() {
  // Send a request updating the backend
  
  // simulation
  backend.input = local.input
  update()
}

function localChange() {
  local.input = elements.input.value
  if (local.input === backend.input) {
    delete local.input
  }
  render()
}

function render() {
  input.value = 'input' in local ? local.input : backend.input
  
  let state = ''
  if ('input' in local) {
    state += `Local: "${local.input}"<br/>`
  }
  state += `Backend: "${backend.input}"<br/>`
  elements.stateView.innerHTML = state
}

// Setup events
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  elements.input = document.getElementById('input')
  elements.input.addEventListener('keyup', localChange)
  elements.input.addEventListener('change', save)
  
  elements.stateView = document.getElementById('stateView')
  
  update()
})
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Add you data here">
<p id="stateView"></p>
```

Notice that in this case if the user is editing and it’s the same I just ignore the local state. Also, because I’m not really making requests, everything is instantaneous.

Comment: Will the inputs change the values in the spreadsheet?

Comment: @JohnEmmanuelDelaCruz You need to do the call to `google.script.run` manually (in this case would be on the function `save`)